# Create Navigation Background CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I came upon this website today:

http://leaverou.me/2010/12/checkered-stripes-other-background-patterns-with-css3-gradients/

and made me curious as to how you create the strip coming out from behind the white div without using images?  If anyone can tell me, I'd surely appreciate it.  Also, if someone doesn't understand what I mean, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of tutorials for making 3D Ribbons (as it's called). Example: http://www.pvmgarage.com/2010/01/how-to-create-depth-and-nice-3d-ribbons-only-using-css3/

Comment: Thank you!  I couldn't remember what they were called and so that's why I couldn't Google for the tutorials.